# Can we abuse notation and write equations in differential one-form?

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, differentials

Consider a simple equation with a [one-form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-form) on both sides ([mathworld.wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Differentialk-Form.html) is also aware of this):

$$ y\mathrm{d}x = \mathrm{d}y $$

This is a perfectly valid [abuse of notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_notation#Derivative). We can carry the $y$ over to the right, then integrate both sides:

$$\int \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y} $$

to get

$$ x = \log y + C $$

or we can carry the differential of $x$ and get a normal differential equation:

$$y = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=y'(x)$$

which we can plug into `DSolve` and find `y[x]->C[1]Exp[x]`

The question is, can we get Mathematica to accept this abuse of notation like so

```
DSolve[y \[DifferentialD]x == \[DifferentialD]y, y, x]
```

and solve equations involving infinitesimal values on both sides?

Unfortunately, searching the documentation or this site for "k-form", "one-form", "differential form" did not yield helpful results.

Comment: This is essentially a division by $dx$, which is, of course, all, that is needed in this simple example. I'll try to find something more interesting.

Comment: Well, my first thought was to put a differrential into a function. `\[DifferentialD]y == Log[1 + \[DifferentialD]x]`. Then naively you'd expect `y==C+x`, but your code returns `y==C+x Log[2]`. But this feels like cheating. I'm exploring options with functions of multiple arguments or higher order equations for the moment.

Comment: Well, the feeling of cheatiness was perfectly valid then. I'm certainly not insisting on a solution to automate such irregular and often simply invalid constructs, I'd just like to find a more or less general approach to putting equations from the OP into Mathematica. I slightly generalized your suggestion with this snippet `(-dif[(y/x)] == 2 x Tan[y/x] dif[x]) /. {y -> y[x]} /. {dif[g_] -> 
   Dt[g, x]*dif[x]}` which should properly handle differentials of arbitrary things, not just `x` and `y`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, now I'm feeling stupid.

First I asked [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20y%20dx%3Ddy) and it interpreted my query correctly. Then I did

```
WolframAlpha["solve y dx=dy", {{"Input", 1}, "Input"}]
(* HoldComplete[y Dt[x] == Dt[y]] *)
```

That gave me a clue for the proper notation.

```
DSolve[y[x] Dt[x] == Dt[y[x]], y, x]
(* {{y -> Function[{x}, E^x C[1]]}} *)
```

Mathematica handles differentials out of the box just fine.

Comment: I think you really uncovered a blind spot! Now the procedure seems to be evident: `Dt[y[x]]` evaluates to `y'[x] Dt[x]` and for any correct DE `Dt[x]` will be eliminated finally. But these thoughts never came to me!

Comment: When searching for `y` one would be looking to eliminate `Dt[y[x]]` and integrate whatever it is expressed as. But I see what's happening, you are indeed correct.

Comment: Maybe it's also worth pointing out that *Mathematica* "knows" what you're thinking if you enter `TraditionalForm[Dt[x]]`. The output is $\mathbb{d}x$.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if the following is a recent enhancement of `DSolve` (V12.2 or earlier).  If it is, I don't know when it happened.  My past experience led me to think it would give an error.  The first line is applied below to the OP's original code.  We don't need to rewrite `y` as a function of `x`; it is done for us.  `DSolve` returns an implicit solution with an inactivated `Solve`.  (I don't know why, but that is, roughly speaking, the typical method in a differential equations course.)

```
Activate@Block[{DifferentialD = Dt}, 
  DSolve[y \[DifferentialD]x == \[DifferentialD]y, y, x]]

(*  {{y[x] -> -E^x C[1]}}  *)
```

Unfortunately, the original `DSolve[y \[DifferentialD]x == \[DifferentialD]y, y, x]` still gives an error.