# Work of a force field

Tags: function-construction, physics

I have a parameter curve in 3d:

```
r1[t_] := {Cos[2 Pi t], Sin[2 Pi t], t}
r2[t_] := {1, 0, t}
r3[t_] := {1 - 1/2 Sin[Pi t], 0, 1/2 - Cos[Pi t]}
```

with a vector field:

```
F[x_, y_, z_] := {-2 x y + z^3, -1 - x^2, 3 x z^2};

r = {x, y, z}
```

Now I want to calculate work of force field as the path integral for `r1`, `r2` and `r3` as a procedure, that uses arguments `F(r)` and `r(t)` and times `t0` & `t1`.

Has someone an idea how to realize it into *Mathematica* code?

Thanks a lot!

---

looks great!

I also want to visualize the curves in a ParametricPlot3D, I did this:

```
r1[t] = ParametricPlot3D[{{Cos[2*Pi*t], Sin[2*Pi*t], t}}, {t, 0, 1}]
r2[t] = ParametricPlot3D[{{1, 0, t}}, {t, 0, 1}]
r3[t] = ParametricPlot3D[{{1 - 1/2*Sin[Pi*t], 0, 
    1/2*(1 - Cos[Pi*t])}}, {t, 0, 1}]
```

How can I define the path of the curves from `(1,0,0) to (1,0,1)` ?

Comment: It should be `Cos[2*Pi*t]` or `Cos[2 Pi t]`, not `cos(2*Pi*t)`.

Answer (score 8):

It is more about physics, rather than *Mathematica*. You should express the work as follows: $ \int\vec{F}\cdot\vec{r}_1'(t)\, \mathrm dt $ After that it is easy to write the *Mathematica* expression:

```
Integrate[
 F[r1[t][[1]], r1[t][[2]], r1[t][[3]]].D[r1[t], t], {t, t0, t1}]

(*  1/4 (-4 t0^3 Cos[2 \[Pi] t0] + 4 t1^3 Cos[2 \[Pi] t1] + 
   5 Sin[2 \[Pi] t0] + Sin[6 \[Pi] t0] - 5 Sin[2 \[Pi] t1] - 
   Sin[6 \[Pi] t1]) *)
```

The rest you can do analogously.

Have fun!

Answer (score 4):

I guess codes below would work:

```
(F @@ #).D[#, t] & /@ {r1[t], r2[t], r3[t]} // Simplify
Integrate[%, {t, t0, t1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways, one involving `DSolve` and differential one-forms (the first one is like the others, except for being packaged up in a line integral function).  See [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/82647/4999) by [LLlAMnYP](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/26956/lllamnyp) for the `DSolve` approach.

```
ClearAll[lineInt];

(* integrate a vector field *)
lineInt[F_?VectorQ, c : (X_?VectorQ -> rt_?VectorQ), {t_, a_, b_}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[Integrate]] := 
  Integrate[(F /. Thread[c]).D[rt, t], {t, a, b}, opts];

(* integrate a one form *)
oneFormQ[ω_, X_] := (* linear && homogenenous in differentials Dt@X *)
   Internal`LinearQ[ω, Dt[X]] && PossibleZeroQ[ω /. Thread[Dt[X] -> 0]];
lineInt[ω_, c : (X_?VectorQ -> rt_?VectorQ), {t_, a_, b_}, 
   opts : OptionsPattern[DSolve]] := Module[{W},
   DSolveValue[
     {{Dt[W[t]] == ω, Dt[X] == Dt[rt]} /. Thread[X -> Through[X[t]]],
      W[a] == 0, Through[X[a]] == rt /. t -> a},
     W[b],
     t, opts] /; oneFormQ[ω, X]
   ];

X = {x, y, z};

lineInt[(F @@ X).Dt[X], X -> r1[t], {t, t0, t1}] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {0.196, 1/4 (-4 t0^3 Cos[2 π t0] + 4 t1^3 Cos[2 π t1] + 
      5 Sin[2 π t0] + Sin[6 π t0] - 5 Sin[2 π t1] - 
      Sin[6 π t1])}
*)

lineInt[F @@ X, X -> r1[t], {t, t0, t1}] // RepeatedTiming
(*
  {2.19, 1/4 (-4 t0^3 Cos[2 π t0] + 4 t1^3 Cos[2 π t1] + 
      5 Sin[2 π t0] + Sin[6 π t0] - 5 Sin[2 π t1] - 
      Sin[6 π t1])}
*)
```

`Integrate` must do a lot of checking that `DSolve` skips, I guess.