# ApplySides Integrate to equations in differential one-form

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

Related to this [Can we abuse notation and write equations in differential one-form?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82642/78)

Is it possible to `ApplySides` a form of `Integrate` to an equation in differential one-form, so to achieve the following sequence:

$$ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{y}\mathrm{d}y $$

`ApplySides[Integrate, \[DifferentialD]x == 1/y \[DifferentialD]y]`

$$\int \mathrm{d}x = \int \frac{1}{y}\mathrm{d}y $$

$$ x = \log y $$

Comment: `\[Integral]\[DifferentialD]x==\[Integral]1/y\[DifferentialD]y` is valid code, though it of course doesn't use `ApplySides`.  Many `Apply`-esque things, like `OperatorApplied`, fail to insert `\[Integral]` before a syntax error.  Same problem with `Hold` and friends.  Perhaps these are worth adding to the question.

Comment: I added an answer to the linked Q&A that applies `DSolve` to a differential equation in such a form.  It does not integrate each. so it does not do what is asked; but you still might find it convenient.

Answer (score 4):

The use of `\[DifferentialD]x` to input an integral only work when converting boxes or a string representation.  If you already have the equation in the OP in the kernel, it has the form

```
Equal[DifferentialD[x], Times[Power[y, -1], DifferentialD[y]]]
```

The way to apply an integral sign to it is to convert back to box form (or a string).

```
ApplySides[
 Fold[ToExpression[
     RowBox[{"\[Integral]", MakeBoxes[#, StandardForm]}]] &, #, 
   Cases[#, _DifferentialD, {0, Infinity}]] &,
 \[DifferentialD]x == 1/y \[DifferentialD]y]

(*  x == Log[y]  *)

(* assumes DifferentialD[..] is a factor *)
ApplySides[
 Fold[ToExpression[
     "\[Integral]" <> ToString[#/#2, InputForm] <> 
      ToString[#2, InputForm]] &, #, 
   Cases[#, _DifferentialD, {0, Infinity}]] &,
 \[DifferentialD]x == 1/y \[DifferentialD]y]

(*  x == Log[y]  *)
```

Another alternative would be to parse the expression and apply `Integrate`, which seems simpler in the present case when I look at it:

```
(* assumes DifferentialD[..] is a factor *)
ApplySides[
 Fold[Integrate[#/#2, First@#2] &, #, 
   Cases[#, _DifferentialD, {0, Infinity}]] &,
 \[DifferentialD]x == 1/y \[DifferentialD]y]

(*  x == Log[y]  *)
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
f[ex_] := (int = (ex /. DifferentialD[_] -> 1); 
  dif = ex /. x___   DifferentialD[a_] -> a /. DifferentialD[a_] -> a;
   Inactive[Integrate][ex /. DifferentialD[_] -> 1 , dif])

ApplySides[f, \[DifferentialD]x == 1/y \[DifferentialD]y]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Here's a different approach, more general than asked for. It's not as suitable for [Can we abuse notation and write equations in differential one-form?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82642) as for here, perhaps.  In the following, it is not necessary to write one of the variables as a function of the others.  It is more general in that it will integrate exact one-forms, not just separable ones, as well as two-variable forms for which an integrating factor can be found.  And it will integrate exact forms of three or more variables.  (It won't search for an integrating factor when there are more than two variables, however.)

```
ClearAll[integrate1Form];
integrate1Form::nonhom = "Not a homogeneous 1-form.";
integrate1Form::inexact = "Not an exact 1-form.";
integrate1Form[eq_] :=
  Module[{U, dvars, vars, res, vf, mu, P, Q},
   dvars = Union@Cases[eq, _DifferentialD, Infinity];
   vars = dvars[[All, 1]];
   vf = Replace[
     CoefficientArrays[eq, dvars],
     {{0, one_} :> Normal@one,
      {Except[0], __} :> $Failed}];
   If[Length@vf == 2,
    {P, Q} = vf;
    mu = DSolve`DSolveFirstOrderODEDump`IntegratingFactor[Q, 
      P, -D[P, y] + D[Q, x], x, y];
    If[FreeQ[mu, $Failed],
     vf *= mu]
    ];
   If[FreeQ[vf, $Failed],
    res = DSolveValue[
      D[U @@ vars, {vars}] == vf,
      U @@ vars, vars],
    Message[integrate1Form::nonhom];
    res = $Failed
    ];
   If[! FreeQ[res, DSolveValue],
    Message[integrate1Form::inexact]
    ];
   Simplify[res == 0] /; FreeQ[res, $Failed | DSolveValue]
   ];
```

A separable equation:

```
integrate1Form[\[DifferentialD]x == 
  1/y \[DifferentialD]y + \[DifferentialD]y]
```

> ```
> (*  x + C[1] == y + Log[y]  *)
> ```

An equation with an integrating factor:

```
integrate1Form[\[DifferentialD]x == 
  1/y \[DifferentialD]y + x \[DifferentialD]y]
```

> ```
> (*  E^-y x + C[1] == ExpIntegralEi[-y]  *)
> ```

An equation in which an integrating factor could not be found:

```
integrate1Form[(x + y) \[DifferentialD]x == 1/y \[DifferentialD]y]
```

> integrate1Form::inexact :  Not an exact 1-form.
>
> ```
> (*  integrate1Form[(x + y) \[DifferentialD]x == \[DifferentialD]y/y]  *)
> ```

An exact form in three variables:

```
integrate1Form[
 2 x y \[DifferentialD]x + (x^2 - 2 y z^3 ) \[DifferentialD]y == 
  3 y^2 z^2 \[DifferentialD]z]
```

> ```
> (*  x^2 y + C[1] == y^2 z^3  *)
> ```