How to find all independent first integrals (or general integrals) of a system of first-order differential equations?
Are there any built-in functions or custom functions that can solve for all independent first integrals (or general integrals  https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/General_integral  or https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22General+integral%22 ) of a system of first-order differential equations? I haven't found any relevant generic code or commands on this forum. However, these built-in functions might be useful for writing the code: "VariationalMethods FirstIntegrals[]", CompleteIntegral. The examples I provided are not meant to solve them all, but rather to offer some references and validation examples for improving the generality of the code. Thank you in advance!
(1)
\begin{cases}
\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{2xy}{x^2 - y^2 - z^2}, \\
\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x} = \frac{2xz}{x^2 - y^2 - z^2}.
\end{cases}
eq11 = D[y[x], x] == 2 x y[x]/(x^2 - y[x]^2 - z[x]^2);

eq12 = D[z[x], x] == 2 x z[x]/(x^2 - y[x]^2 - z[x]^2);

all independent first integrals (or general integrals):
\begin{cases}
\frac{y}{z} = c_1, \\
\frac{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}{y} = c_2
\end{cases}
(2)
\begin{cases}
\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{xz} = \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{yz} = \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{xy}
\end{cases}
eq2 = Dt[x]/(x*z) == Dt[y]/(y*z) == Dt[z]/(x*y);

all independent first integrals (or general integrals):
\begin{cases}
xy - z^2 = c_1, \\
\frac{x}{y} = c_2
\end{cases}
(3)
\begin{cases}
\frac{dx}{z} = \frac{dy}{xz} = \frac{dz}{y};
\end{cases}
eq3 = Dt[x]/z == Dt[y]/(x*z) == Dt[z]/y;

all independent first integrals (or general integrals):
\begin{cases}
x^2 - 2y = c_1, \quad x^3 - 3x(x^2 - 2y) - 3z^2 = c_2,
\end{cases}
(4)
\begin{cases}
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{z}{x}, \quad  \frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{z(y + 2z - 1)}{x(y - 1)}.
\end{cases}
eq4 = {
  D[y,x] == z/x,
  D[z,x] == z*(y + 2*z - 1)/(x*(y - 1))
};

all independent first integrals (or general integrals):
\begin{cases}
z = (y - 1)^2c_1 - (y - 1), \quad -(y - 1)^{-1} - x = c - c_1,
\end{cases}

What's "independent first integrals"? Can you add a reference for it? I fail to find anything useful with a quick googling.

The reference link has been added.


Please show us the Mathematica code for these equation systems so we can play with them easier. 2. Hint: https://i.sstatic.net/vTzqnHWo.png


Your definition for eq4 is invalid, and you've coded eq2 and eq3 in a nonstandard way (if it's not wrong). Please double check them. Or are you expecting a function that allows abuse of notation as discussed in e.g. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82642/1871 ? Please clarify, the question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

In general, Mathematica can do only what humans can do, although faster and more accurately.  So, if a general algorithm exists for finding first integrals, at least in principle, then Mathematica might have a function to implement that algorithm, and almost certainly such a Mathematica function could be written.  Otherwise, you are out of luck.
